# Focus textbox not work in some cases

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, .net-4.0

using this code I manage to focus to a textbox using MVVM. When the form is loaded or when I click on a button "focus" works perfectly, but after a query in the background, no longer works. Im use MVVM Light.

```
public static class FocusExtension
{
    public static bool GetIsFocused(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsFocusedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsFocused(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsFocusedProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFocusedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "IsFocused", typeof(bool), typeof(FocusExtension),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, null, OnCoerceValue));

    private static object OnCoerceValue(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {
        if ((bool)baseValue)
        {
            ((UIElement)d).Focus();
        }
        else if (((UIElement)d).IsFocused)
        {
            Keyboard.ClearFocus();
        }
        return (bool)baseValue;
    }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    try
    {
        /////////////////////////////
        SQL QUERY
        /////////////////////////////
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        ...
    }
}).ContinueWith(x =>
{

    IsFocused = true; // FOCUS NOT WORK HERE!!!

}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

**EDIT**

```
private bool _isFocused = true;

public bool IsFocused
{
    get { return _isFocused; }
    set
    {
        _isFocused = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsFocused");
    }
}
```

Comment: where is IsFocused on viewmodel ? does it notify changes ?

Comment: @Muds thx, yes, go to edit to check